# I am confused in two ways to create one to many relationship in code first migration . Which one to choose?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I have used two ways to create one to many relationships in code first migration and I do not know what is the difference between each of them.

**First method:**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Method:**

```
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

They both have the same result. See the relationship: [Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cPDm.png)

So why we use `ICollection` in student table if we get the same relationship?

Comment: Thank you so much. So it's mean the database will remain the same. If I include Ilist<Courses> in student or not. If I add this property then I will be able to access all courses of one student. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relationship in the entity framework always has two ends, a navigation property on each side and an Entity Framework that maps them together automatically by convention.

In your example, Student and Course class have a one-to-many relationship. Here, Id (Student table) will become the primary key of the Student table and ForeignKey attributes for Student_Id property in Course class in order to make foreign key.You have to pass Student entity in ForeignKey attribute of Course class. Thus, the code first creates a one-to-many relation between Student and Course class using  [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx) attributes.

For Example:

You can simple get all `course Name` of a student by using negation property of student able (Courses) like:

```
_context.Students
       .Include(s => s.Courses)     
       .Courses.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList();
```

You can fiend more information about [One-to-Many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) this link.

Comment: Okay, it helped me a lot. Can you tell me how can I use ICollection<Course> to fetch data from the database?

Comment: For example  var student = _context.Students.ToList(); to fetch all student data.

Comment: Now how can I use ICollection<Course> to load data?

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq i update my answer and add a example.

Answer (score 0):

In first method you are assigning a student to the course entity that means only one student will be assigned in a course which I think is wrong as there will be many students doing the same course.

Ideally course should not be dependant on students entity. You should assign the students with correct course. If a student can take multiple courses then second method is almost correct only thing is that you can remove the student property from course entity as below.
But if a student can take only one course then you can modify the student entity and assign a single course instead of list of course.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```